# ExtJs3. Defect when the upload file

Tags: image, upload, extjs3

To upload a file using **inputType: 'file'**, and for a *form* prescribed **fileUpload: true**.
Everything works fine, the file is saved. But after saving the file block *success* (from ajax request) is not satisfied. Ie all the stops to **waitMsg: 'Saving Data ...'**.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, remember to set the Content-Type header to correct MIME type in your server response: "text/html". Anything else will result in ExtJS throwing an error when decoding your response.

In PHP, this can be done with

```
<?php    
    header('Content-type: text/html');
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
?>
```

From ExtJS API docs:

> If the server is using JSON to send the return object, then the Content-Type header must be > set to "text/html" in order to tell the browser to insert the text unchanged into the document body.
>
> Characters which are significant to an HTML parser must be sent as HTML entities, so encode > "<" as "<", "&" as "&" etc.

Make sure you do escape special HTML characters as suggested. If you don't, ExtJS may still succeed in parsing the server response but with unexpected twists: single quotes in HTML-like strings turn into `"'`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should send back server result to extjs form by print this on server:

```
echo '{success:true, data: "save" }'
```